# Адекватный счётчик времени fromNow moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

не получаться разобраться с библиотекой monetjs подскажите пожалуйста. Нужно посчитать сколько времени прошло с определенного момента, то есть поможет метод [fromNow](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/), код:

```
    moment.locale('ru');

    setInterval(() => {
        this.last_update = moment.unix(this.last_update_time).fromNow();
        console.log(this.last_update);
    }, 1000);
```

и получаю в консоле: [image: Демонстрация fromNow] замете вовсе не считало секунды, хотя в документации `fromNow` показано что ещё может быть `seconds ago` [image: Таблица из документации] позже нашёл метод [relativeTimeThreshold](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) который позволял установить пороговые значения для всех ключей из таблицы, в код добавил (поcле `moment.locale('ru');`):

```
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('ss', 3);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 10);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);
```

Получил:[image: Консоль]

Как включить отображение `seconds ago` и при этом получить адекватный счётчик времени? сначала от 0 до 5: Несколько секунд назад, после просто секунды, и т.д

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте ваше сообщение в соответствии с правилами [правописания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Орфография_русского_языка). Хотя бы постарайтесь